# Mass Java code file modifying - Remove methods, annotations, etc

Tags: java, refactoring

I got a bundle of code from an very old project, which they generated many redundancy methods and annotations.

Is there anyway that fast, to remove -method "doOldThing()"- from all classes in this package; remove all @AnnotationObsoluted in all class?

I know that we can use search and replace, but writing regex to delete those take a long time. I guess we could have someway to parse a Java file, then remove "doOldThings()" method, check if @AnnotationObsoluted there then remove. Any idea? Tks.

Comment: I usually just delete or comment out the method/class and then go around to all the source files that have errors in them and resolve them. Even on big projects it generally doesn't take to long.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone interest, here is the code for small util that I wrote to clean up methods (by name) and import statement as well.

```
    import com.googlecode.java2objc.main.Config;
    import com.googlecode.java2objc.main.Main;
    import japa.parser.ASTHelper;
    import japa.parser.JavaParser;
    import japa.parser.ParseException;
    import japa.parser.ast.CompilationUnit;
    import japa.parser.ast.ImportDeclaration;
    import japa.parser.ast.body.*;
    import japa.parser.ast.expr.AnnotationExpr;
    import japa.parser.ast.type.ClassOrInterfaceType;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * User: lent
     * Date: 10/01/2014
     */
    public class CleanUpAndModelRegeneration
    {
        public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, ParseException
        {
            List<File> results =
                    listFilesForFolder(new File("\\LocationOfYourCode"), new ArrayList<File>());

            List<String> javaFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (File codeFile : results)
            {
                // creates an input stream for the file to be parsed
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(codeFile);

                CompilationUnit cu = null;
                try
                {
                    // parse the file
                    cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
                    removeMethod(cu, "toString");
                    removeMethod(cu, "append");
                    removeMethod(cu, "appendFields");
                    removeMethod(cu, "fromValue");
                    optimizeImport(cu);
                    cleanUpInterfaces("ToString", cu.getTypes());
                    cleanUpAnnotationForEnum(cu);

                    // prints the resulting compilation unit to default system output
                    System.out.println(cu.toString());


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                finally
                {
                    in.close();
                }

                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(codeFile, false);
                fileOutputStream.write(cu.toString().getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.flush();

                javaFiles.add(codeFile.toString());
            }

            try
            {
                Config config = new Config();
                Main main = new Main(config, javaFiles);
                main.execute();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private static void cleanUpAnnotationForEnum(CompilationUnit cu)
        {
            for (TypeDeclaration type : cu.getTypes())
            {
                if (type instanceof EnumDeclaration)
                {
                    EnumDeclaration enumDeclaration = (EnumDeclaration) type;
                    if (enumDeclaration.getAnnotations() != null)
                    {
                        enumDeclaration.getAnnotations().clear();
                    }

                    for (BodyDeclaration member : enumDeclaration.getMembers())
                    {
                        List<AnnotationExpr> annotations = member.getAnnotations();
                        if (annotations != null)
                        {
                            annotations.clear();
                        }
                    }
                    for (EnumConstantDeclaration member : enumDeclaration.getEntries())
                    {
                        List<AnnotationExpr> annotations = member.getAnnotations();
                        if (annotations != null)
                        {
                            annotations.clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void cleanUpInterfaces(String interfaceName, List<? extends BodyDeclaration> types)
        {
            for (BodyDeclaration type : types)
            {
                cleanUpInterface(type, interfaceName);
                if (type instanceof TypeDeclaration)
                {
                    List<BodyDeclaration> members = ((TypeDeclaration) type).getMembers();
                    if (members == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    for (BodyDeclaration body : members)
                    {
                        if (body instanceof ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration)
                        {
                            cleanUpInterface(body, interfaceName);
                            cleanUpInterfaces(interfaceName, ((ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration) body).getMembers());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void cleanUpInterface(BodyDeclaration typeDeclaration, String interfaceName)
        {
            if (typeDeclaration instanceof ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration)
            {
                List<ClassOrInterfaceType> interfaceTypes = ((ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration) typeDeclaration).getImplements();
                if (interfaceTypes == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                List<ClassOrInterfaceType> toBeRemove = new ArrayList<ClassOrInterfaceType>();
                for (ClassOrInterfaceType interfaceType : interfaceTypes)
                {
                    if (interfaceType.toString().equals(interfaceName))
                    {
                        toBeRemove.add(interfaceType);
                    }
                }
                interfaceTypes.removeAll(toBeRemove);
            }
        }

        private static void optimizeImport(CompilationUnit cu)
        {
            List<ImportDeclaration> toBeRemove = new ArrayList<ImportDeclaration>();
            if (cu.getImports() == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            for (ImportDeclaration importDeclaration : cu.getImports())
            {
                String importPackageName = importDeclaration.getName().toString();
                if (importPackageName.startsWith("java.io")
                        || importPackageName.startsWith("javax.xml.datatype")
                        || importPackageName.startsWith("java.util")
                        || importPackageName.startsWith("java.math")
                        || importPackageName.startsWith("java.text"))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                toBeRemove.add(importDeclaration);
            }
            cu.getImports().removeAll(toBeRemove);
        }

        public static List<File> listFilesForFolder(final File folder, List<File> result)
        {
            for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles())
            {
                if (fileEntry.isDirectory())
                {
                    listFilesForFolder(fileEntry, result);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        result = new ArrayList<File>();
                    }
                    result.add(fileEntry);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static void removeMethod(CompilationUnit cu, String methodName)
        {
            List<TypeDeclaration> types = cu.getTypes();
            for (TypeDeclaration type : types)
            {
                List<BodyDeclaration> members = type.getMembers();
                cleanUp(methodName, type, members);

                if (type.getAnnotations() != null)
                {
                    type.getAnnotations().clear();
                }
                type.setJavaDoc(null);
                type.setComment(null);
            }
        }

        private static void cleanUp(String methodName, BodyDeclaration type, List<BodyDeclaration> members)
        {
            List<BodyDeclaration> membersToRemove = new ArrayList<BodyDeclaration>();
            for (BodyDeclaration member : members)
            {
                try
                {
                    member.setJavaDoc(null);
                    member.setComment(null);
                    if (member.getAnnotations() != null)
                    {
                        member.getAnnotations().clear();
                    }
                    if (member instanceof MethodDeclaration && methodName.equals(((MethodDeclaration) member).getName()))
                    {
                        membersToRemove.add(member);
                    }
                    if (member instanceof ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration)
                    {
                        cleanUp(methodName, member, ((ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration) member).getMembers());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            if (type instanceof TypeDeclaration)
            {
                ((TypeDeclaration) type).getMembers().removeAll(membersToRemove);
            }
            else if (type instanceof ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration)
            {
                ((ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration) type).getMembers().removeAll(membersToRemove);
            }
            else if (type instanceof EnumDeclaration)
            {
                ((EnumDeclaration) type).getMembers().removeAll(membersToRemove);
            }
        }


        private static void changeMethods(CompilationUnit cu)
        {
            List<TypeDeclaration> types = cu.getTypes();
            for (TypeDeclaration type : types)
            {
                List<BodyDeclaration> members = type.getMembers();
                for (BodyDeclaration member : members)
                {
                    if (member instanceof MethodDeclaration)
                    {
                        MethodDeclaration method = (MethodDeclaration) member;
                        changeMethod(method);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void changeMethod(MethodDeclaration n)
        {
            // change the name of the method to upper case
            n.setName(n.getName().toUpperCase());

            // create the new parameter
            Parameter newArg = ASTHelper.createParameter(ASTHelper.INT_TYPE, "value");

            // add the parameter to the method
            ASTHelper.addParameter(n, newArg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you erase the body of doOldThing():

```
doOldThing() {
}
```

And then inline the method, it should disappear wherever it is used.  If instead you wanted to replace it with a call to doNewThing():

```
doOldThing() {
    doNewThing();
}
```

and then inline.

Comment: I actually want to remove all those doOldThing() method from code files.

Comment: That's what this will do.  When you inline an empty method, the calls to it disappear.

Comment: Sorry for leave this for awhile, but I can't use the solution that you give because it doesn't clean the code which very strictly at our company. In the end, I have to write down a small util using JavaParser, change java code model and write back down.